# Uso da função set e for na mesma estrutura

Tags: python

Eu estou estudando data science através da linguagem Python e me deparei com o seguinte código:

```
world_trends_set = set([trend['name'] for trend in world_trends[0]['trends']])
us_trends_set = set([trend['name'] for trend in us_trends[0]['trends']])
```

Este exemplo eu retirei do livro "Mining-the-Social-Web-2nd-Edition". Eu não consigo entender o porquê do `trend['name']` antes do loop. Eu imagino que o código está criando um conjunto chamado `name` com os itens da primeira linha da coluna `trends`.

Alguém pode me explicar a vantagem do uso da sintaxe dessa forma e me corrigir se eu estiver errado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considerando a linha:

```
world_trends_set = set([trend['name'] for trend in world_trends[0]['trends']])
```

O código equivalente seria:

```
temp = []

for trend in world_trends[0]['trends']:
    temp.append(trend['name'])

world_trends_set = set(temp)
```

O resultado produzido por ambos os códigos será exatamente o mesmo, então, sim, o que o código está fazendo é criar um conjunto a partir de uma lista. Esta lista, por sua vez, é composta pela coluna `name` do valor `trend`. Isto é, `world_trends` é uma lista em que sua posição 0 também é uma lista de dicionários que possuem a coluna `name`.

Considerando que você esteja primeiro criando uma lista, ou seja, armazenando todos os valores em memória, e depois convertendo para um conjunto, não nenhum ganho de performance ou custo de memória. A diferença está mais na escrita do código: a primeira forma é menor e até mais legível para humanos que a segunda. Ou seja, a primeira forma é mais fácil de entender.

Aliás, você pode até remover os colchetes em torno da expressão `for` da seguinte forma:

```
world_trends_set = set(trend['name'] for trend in world_trends[0]['trends'])
```

Dentro dos parenteses teríamos uma *generator expression* sendo convertida para um conjunto. Também não apresentaria melhores de performance, acredito eu, pois converter o *generator* para um conjunto também armazenaria todos os elementos em memória, mas seria uma operação a menos para o Python processar.